# Current state of the art Mars spacesuit?

Tags: mars, spacesuits

What's the current state of the art spacesuit for use on Mars?

I'm wondering about things like size, shape, materials, layering, performance, weight and comfort.

In particular, how thin can the main suit material be while still providing protection from the environment?

Comment: If Mars has an atmosphere of nitrogen, helium, argon and other non toxic gases with a pressure of about 0.2 to 0.4 bar only a closed circuit breathing system would be necessary but no gas tight suit. But the very low pressure of Mars would allow to reduce the micro meteroite protection a little compared to a Moon suite. All other systems of the suit would require the same effort as for the Moon.

Comment: There currently is no Mars spacesuit. There are several concept suits such as NASA's Z-2 or MIT's Bio suit but no fully functional, ready to deploy models.

Comment: Ask hollywood.Probably tight fitting lycra, with lights inside the helmet to illuminate the actors faces.

Comment: I see practically no reason to make it significantly different from the Moon space suits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although no actual mars suit has been built, the most advanced prototype is Dana Newman’s bio suit.  It has a helmet to supply her with breathable oxygen, and is skintight to maintain earth like pressure on her body so that her vital bodily fluids don’t boil off into space.

Comment: Can you add a link to a description of the suit?

Comment: There is not only a gas filled helmet, the problems with gloves and boots were not solved using mechanical counterpressure but using gas pressure too.

Comment: The suit does not maintain earth like pressure to the wearer. The team was aiming 0.3 bar, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_activity_suit). A pressure of about 1 bar would not allow working with the hands wearing gas filled gloves.

Comment: See the questions about similar suits and their problems: [1](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27899/combined-mechanical-counterpressure-and-gas-pressurized-suits), [2](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/2609/what-progress-has-there-been-in-the-design-of-modern-spacesuits/2612#2612), [3](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/27544/what-ever-happened-with-that-pressure-suit-design-based-on-elastic-tension-in-co/27546#27546).

Comment: This seems to be in doubt -- it's been stated that the Bio-Suit probably is a long way from space qualification.